# Route navigation issue in RC4 angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem with the RC4 router behavior since I've updated angular2 version from beta to RC4.
I have following in my systemjs configuration:

```
var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.4'; 
var routerVer = '@3.0.0-beta.1';
```

A method is attached to the button *Load Again* which is part of home.component html and does call the router navigation to the same component. 
With recent upgrades in angular2, `ngOnInit` of the  to same component is not called if it is already called while instantiating the component.

I've to get the same component instantiated again *after routing* to support a business logic in my application.

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.component.html' 
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('in ngOnInit');
  }

  loadAgain(text:string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

**home.component.html:**

```
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <div (click)="loadAgain()" class="col-1-4">
      <button style="cursor:pointer; ">Load Again</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Even though the method executes and calls router navigate, the routing to homeComponent does not happen.
I cannot destroy the initialized component by any means. This used to work in 2.0.0.beta1, but not in RC4.
Has anyone come across this situation?

Comment: There is already beta.2 of the router available.

Comment: Try to navigate to an empty component (blank HTML) and then back to home from there as a workaround.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal, I tried that. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the current router components are reused if the path doesn't change or if only parameter values have changed. This was opt-in in previous router version but is the "default" behavior and there is currently no opt-out. There is an open issue with some discussion but its not sure yet they will implement it.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811